# Migration failed in Wagtail 5.0.1 on MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, django, wagtail

after install wagtail, i have some problems how to use mssql in wagtail cms? i have error when migration wagtail when use mssql, im use wagtail v5 and django v4.2.2

its error log

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The index 'content_object_idx' is dependent on column 'content_type_id'. (5074) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN content_type_id failed because one or more objects access this column. (4922)")`

is it possible use mssql for wagtail cms database?

how to  Solve migration to MSSQL on wagtail cms ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [limitations listed for the mssql-django package](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django#limitations) I suspect you won't be able to run Wagtail on MSSQL. It isn't a fully supported database for Django and I think we use some features that are not available in that package.

But to debug your index problem above, could you please look at the stack trace and tell me which migration file is failing? And I am assuming this is your initial setup so you are starting from an empty database, right?